# Add rows to a DataFrame inside a for loop

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary, row

I'm using a for loop to go through a DataFrame and look if a certain row meets a condition, if so, I need to add it to a different data frame. I'm using a for loop because I've got a list of values that I have to look up.

```
for id in list_Ids:
  list_of_products.append( df[df['ID']==id].to_dict()  ) 

report= pd.Dataframe.from.dict(list_of_products)
```

Inside the loop, I convert every row to a dictionary and I stored in a list, and then I call pd.DataFrame()
at the end. It kinda works, the problem is that is returning a dictionary of the form index: value

```
ID         ProductName      Country    Freight   
{7: 4597}  {7: Milk}        {7:MX}     {7: 96.92}
```

Comment: hmmm what about doing with isin like `report = df[df['ID'].isin(list_Ids)].copy()`?